# How to show result in engineering format with exponent of 3 * n and certain number of digits?

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

Is there a way to make Matlab show the result in engineering format, so exponent is 3 * n, and with a certain number of total digits (not decimal digits) ?

With for example 4 digits the output of these should be:

```
1E4 / 3: 3.333e03
1E5 / 3: 33.33e03
1E6 / 3: 333.3e03
```

Comment: Have a look into [`format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#inputarg_style)

Comment: @EBH It seems he wants to have greater control over the number of digits displayed before and after the decimal point than what **format shortEng** provides

Comment: Do you want this to apply to the command window output or as a function you can use in your programs?

Comment: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec

Comment: I think you might have to make your own. There are some useful tricks, such as pulling out the integer part of a number x with `floor(x)` and getting the number of digits in the integer part of `x` as `floor(log10(x))+1`.

Comment: Just answered a similar question concerning engineering notation output for sprintf and fprintf. However all answers use some sort of workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312572